# How does one define the gradient of a Markov semigroup?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, semigroups-of-operators

In the context of functional inequalities for Markov semigroups $(\mathcal P_t)_{t\ge0}$, what is one denoting by $\nabla\mathcal P_tf$? For example, I've found the following assumption in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602479.pdf):

[image]
[image]

Above, $(\mathcal P_t)_{t\ge0}$ is the semigroup given by $$\mathcal P_t(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[\Phi_t(\;\cdot\;,x)\in B\right]$$ and $\phi$ is a Lipschitz continuous Fréchet differentiable function. However, there is no assumption ensuring that $\mathcal P_t$ preserves Fréchet differentiability. So, how does one understand the differential ${\rm D}\mathcal P_t$?

Comment: A probabilistic way to understand $D \mathcal{P}_t$ is using a *Bismut-Elworthy-Li* formula; see, e.g., Theorem 10.3 of http://www.hairer.org/notes/Imperial.pdf  Note that this formula involves the underlying process (10.1) and its derivative (10.2).

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Maybe I don't understand the result, but isn't Theorem 10.3 an identity for ${\rm D}\mathcal P_t$ for the particular flow given by the solution of $(10.1)$? My question is more basic: What kind of differential is ${\rm D}\mathcal P_t$? Is it the ordinary Fréchet derivative? I mean, as indicated in the paper, $x\mapsto\Phi_t(\omega,x)$ is Fréchet differentiable for all $(\omega,t)$. Does this imply that $\mathcal P_tf$ is Fréchet differentiable for all Fréchet differentiable $f$?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Or do we need to understand it in terms of the ["modulus of gradient"](https://books.google.com/books?id=831Nq24pR1oC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22lim+sup%22+%22locally+lipschitz%22&source=bl&ots=DwvR1pH6XT&sig=ACfU3U2vYoUvVbQtyeuo_NjjKHS9YtX9Kg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6oZH47e3pAhUB3qQKHacPC14Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22lim%20sup%22%20%22locally%20lipschitz%22&f=false) (local Lipschitz constant)?

Comment: $D \mathcal{P}_t$ is a Fréchet derivative defined by directional derivatives of $\mathcal{P}_t \phi$.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee So, is it a general property that if $x\mapsto\Phi_t(\omega,x)$ is Fréchet differentiable, then $\mathcal P_tf$ is Fréchet differentiable for all Fréchet differentiable $f$? It seems like the authors of the paper assume this. If so, do you have a reference for that at hand?

Comment: A nice reference is the following book by Cerrai: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540421368. The idea is to use a stochastic representation of $\mathcal{P}_t f(x)$ in terms of an expectation involving the underlying stochastic process, show the process is mean-square differentiable with respect to the initial point, differentiate the stochastic representation and then interchange the derivative with the expectation as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217702/when-can-we-interchange-the-derivative-with-an-expectation

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I've got a subsequent question regarding a bound for a gradient flow of a stochastic Navier-Stokes equation: https://mathoverflow.net/q/364005/91890. It would be great if you could take a look.